# Bootstrap sticky footer solution works except when divs start stacking

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using the template idea from here:

https://gist.github.com/seyDoggy/e919a429b2459aedf509

```
<div class="container">
    ...
</div>

<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        ...
    </div>
</footer>
```

This works great, except when divs being to stack (responsively). Then, the footer is no longer visible. Does anyone know of a simple fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Change sticky footer css to this

```
/* Sticky footer styles
-------------------------------------------------- */
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

HTML:

```
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

code above is based from [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/)

Comment: I've tried this I think. The footer seems to always stick to the bottom in an unresponsive way, i.e. to the bottom of the window always instead of the bottom of the entire window (last element displayed). Not sure if that makes any sense. I'll try it again though.